# Add an icon to a Perl/GTK application

Tags: perl, gtk, icons

I've written a little app in perl/Gtk, now I want to add an icon to it. I"ve got a jpg file. 
The app is very basic, and of course use a Gtk2::Window object.

I was thought to use [Image::Base::Gtk2::Gdk::Pixbuf](https://metacpan.org/module/Image%3a%3aBase%3a%3aGtk2%3a%3aGdk%3a%3aPixbuf) but Gtk2::Window->set_default_icon only want a Gtk2::Gdk::Pixbuf object, and I have not managed to create one (if someone can show me). I'm on a debian with perl-5.14.2.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Um... so... have you tried a google search for "perl gtk2 window icon"? I did... it shows a ton of results that look good.

Comment: Oh, got it:

    my $navIco = Gtk2::Gdk::Pixbuf->new_from_file("./mltwb.png");
    $window->set_default_icon($navIco);

Comment: @Kharec, glad you could find the answer yourself. Could you please post that as an answer and mark the question answered? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, got it!

```
use Image::Base::Gtk2::Gdk::Pixbuf;
my $navIco = Gtk2::Gdk::Pixbuf->new_from_file("./mltwb.png");  `   
$window->set_default_icon($navIco);`
```

Just had to read doc. Thanks folks!